# how to convert a table into another based on each Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following table(each name is unique):

TABLE1:

```
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| id | workflow | tire1_approver | tire2_approver | tire3_approver | tire4_approver |
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1  | 1        | John           | Mike           | Tom            | Kevin          |
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2  | 2        | Mike           | Andrew         | An             | Bob            | 
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I need to translate it into the following table, a person can appear more than once:

TABLE2:

```
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | ID | Name   | Position       |  Workflow | upper_level_approver |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | 1  | John   | tire1_approver | 1         | Mike                 |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | 2  | Mike   | tire2_approver | 1         | Tom                  |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | 3  | Tom    | tire3_approver | 1         | Kevin                |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | 4  | Kevin  | tire4_approver | 1         | N/A                  |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | 5  | Mike   | tire1_approver | 2         | Andrew               |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | 6  | Andrew | tire2_approver | 2         | An                   |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | 7  | An     | tire3_approver | 2         | Bob                  |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
    | 8  | Bob    | tire4_approver | 2         | N/A                  |
    +----+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

I'm using sql developer, i have tried loop and join but aren't able to get to what I want.

TABLE1 and TABLE2 are both in the database, 
Ultimately I would like to store this in the a stored Procedure, when the Front end makes an update to TABLE1, it also calls this procedure and automatically updates TABLE2.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a cross join (instead of the `unpivot` operator). This will work in older versions of Oracle. Simulated data and query output are the same as in my other answer (with `unpivot`).

The OP did not mention whether `null` is possible in the input table (in the approver columns). If it is possible, this cross join solution will handle them differently from the `unpivot` solution. The `unpivot` solution can be modified to produce the same result as the cross join, by using the optional `include nulls` directive in the `unpivot` clause. Or, if the `null` values should not be included, that can be handled in the cross join solution with a `where` condition.

```
select id, name, position, workflow,
       lead(name, 1, 'N/A') over (partition by id, workflow order by lvl)
         as upper_level_approver
from   ( select t.id, 
                case h.lvl when 1 then t.tire1_approver
                           when 2 then t.tire2_approver
                           when 3 then t.tire3_approver
                           when 4 then t.tire4_approver
                end
                  as name, 
                case h.lvl when 1 then 'tire1_approver'
                           when 2 then 'tire2_approver'
                           when 3 then 'tire3_approver'
                           when 4 then 'tire4_approver'
                end 
                  as position,
                t.workflow,
                h.lvl
         from   table1 t
                cross join
                ( select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 4 ) h
    )
;
```

Comment: @LukeYang - lesson from this though: please ALWAYS include your Oracle version in all your posts, here and on any other web sites. As you see, the version is a crucial detail in any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Oracle version, you may or may not be able to use the solution below. It uses the `UNPIVOT` operator, so it requires Oracle 11.2 or higher. In earlier versions, you can use a cross join.

```
   with
     table1 ( id, workflow, tire1_approver, tire2_approver,
                                            tire3_approver, tire4_approver )
       as (
            select 1, 1, 'John', 'Mike'  , 'Tom', 'Kevin' from dual union all
            select 2, 2, 'Mike', 'Andrew', 'An' , 'Bob'   from dual
          )
-- End of simulated table (for testing; not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select  id, name, position, workflow,
        lead(name, 1, 'N/A') over ( partition by id, workflow order by lvl )
          as upper_level_approver
from    table1
unpivot ( name for (position, lvl) in ( tire1_approver as ('tire1_approver', 1),
                                        tire2_approver as ('tire2_approver', 2),
                                        tire3_approver as ('tire3_approver', 3),
                                        tire4_approver as ('tire4_approver', 4)
                                      )
        )
;

ID  NAME    POSITION         WORKFLOW  UPPER_LEVEL_APPROVER
--  ------  --------------  ---------  --------------------
 1  John    tire1_approver          1  Mike  
 1  Mike    tire2_approver          1  Tom   
 1  Tom     tire3_approver          1  Kevin 
 1  Kevin   tire4_approver          1  N/A     
 2  Mike    tire1_approver          2  Andrew
 2  Andrew  tire2_approver          2  An    
 2  An      tire3_approver          2  Bob   
 2  Bob     tire4_approver          2  N/A
```